# android postDelayed and removeCallbacksAndMessages sync

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, synchronization, runnable

my problem is this:  I use Handler.postDelayed() to run animation after 500ms. Later in code I use Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages() cause sometimes I want to run another animation instead. The problem is that sometimes first animation is started but not finished and I think this is sync problem.

Is there a way to check if Runnable given to postDelayed() is started and in that case cancel removeCallbacksAndMessages()?

If run() from this Runnable is started, does removeCallbacksAndMessages has any effect?

The code is something like this:

```
Handler hand = new Handler();
if (counter==2) {
    one = (ImageView) findViewById(img_id);
    two = im;
    hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    applyAnim(0, 90, one, false);
    applyAnim(0, 90, two, false);
    counter = 0;
        }
    }, 750);
} else (counter == 3) {
    im.setClickable(false);
    hand.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    counter = 1;
    applyScndAnim(0, 90, one, false);
    applyScndAnim(0, 90, two, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you post some task or send some message this objects are added to a queue. When you call removeCallbacksAndMessages this queue is cleaned. But tasks or messages that are being dispatched (already pulled from queue) when you call removeCallbacksAndMessages will not be cancelled. If you want to stop a task do it as a thread:

```
public class DrawableTask implements Runnable{
    private boolean cancel = false;
    private boolean isBeingDispatched = false;
    public void cancel(){
        if (this.isBeingDispatched())
            this.cancel = true;
    }
    public boolean isBeingDispatched(){ return isBeingDispatched;}
    public void run(){
        isBeingDispatched = true;
        while(!cancel){
            //refresh 
        }
        cancel = false;
        isBeingDispatched = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
private boolean cancel = false;
private boolean isBeingDispatched = false;

public void cancel(){
    if (this.isBeingDispatched())
        this.cancel = true;
}
public boolean isBeingDispatched(){ return isBeingDispatched;}

public void setHandlers(){
    Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
             YourClassName.this.cancel = false;
             YourClassName.this.isBeingDispatched = true;
             while(! YourClassName.this.cancel){

                  //refresh
             }
             YourClassName.this.cancel = false;
             YourClassName.this.isBeingDispatched = false;
        }
    };
}
```

So you can add this cancel option into your handler. When message arrives handler will execute this code and if during execution you call cancel() method handler will halt whatever he was doing on while.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how do I now if this message is pulled from queue? That's my main issue here. Because calling removeCallbacksAndMessages() is pointless if message is already dispatched...

Comment: You can see on my answer the solution. Basically do the same but think that now the execution is on handleMessage().

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I understand that Handler has message system, and even looked at hasMessage() method to check if my message is still in the queue, but hasMessage() requires some message id that I don't understand what it is.  If you take a look at my example, is there a way that I could check if my queued Runnable is pulled before calling removeCallbacksAndMessages()?

Sorry, if you already answered my question and I'm simply to ignorant to undestand it. Btw, I did read the class API, but still no luck...Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: When the task or message has been dequeued and is being dispatched there is no method to know its state. If you ask hasMessage() to a message that is being dispatched it should return false.
Solution: put a flag. Editing post to add flag..

Comment: Now you can know if your message or task is being dispatched at this moment, and if it is cancel it. Edit done.